# Is it possible to have Access stop automatically resizing the controls on my form after I've adjusted them?

Tags: forms, ms-access, controls, vba

For example, I have a textbox that I need to have a `Left` property of exactly 18.281cm, but as soon as I hit enter, it automatically changes to 18.282cm.

The biggest problem is that the way it changes the number is unpredictable. For example, it seems to only do this with specific numbers since sometimes it leaves the number alone.

Another thing to mention is that the amount it changes the number by varies, it isn't always an increase of 0.001cm, sometimes it's even a decrease. Occasionally there are times I can trick it, so if it won't let me change it to 18.279cm, I can type in 18.280cm and then it automatically changes it to 18.279cm, but this happens rarely.

This problem happens with different controls as well, not only with `Left`. It also does this with `Height` and `Width` just as two more examples. I've been trying to search for another instance of this happening, but I can't find any records of this problem happening to anyone else. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Why must the value be so very specific? What's wrong with 18.282cm vs. 18.281? I believe these values are actually set that way by the application, and you cannot coerce them to the values you want (but I do not have a source for this). This does have a benefit of *helping* to ensure your form controls are sized similarly.

Comment: HansUp: I did have Snap to Grid enabled, but after disabling it, it didn't change anything, but thanks anyway!

Gaffi: The reason I need it to be exact is because I'm trying to line a bunch of textboxes together where the gap between them is 0.292cm. If the textbox is resized to 18.282cm it makes one box inconsistent with the rest of the boxes. It actually turns out to be more than just one box since this isn't the only box with the resizing problem, but hopefully you see what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it does this is because the measurement is actually [**twips**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip)

18.280cm is not an exact number of twips, so it counds to the nearest twip
18.280cm = 10363.464566929 twips

10363 twips = 18.279180556cm
10364 twips = 18.280944444cm

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was somewhat afraid that the answer would be something like this. Does this mean for each textbox I wish to line up I need to set up the "Left", "Height", "Width" properties on VBA to ensure they're lined up correctly? And quick follow up, that would also mean if I wanted to change the location of the boxes on the form, I'd have to manually change the entries for each box right?

Comment: You can select multiple controls, then changing a property from the property sheet will apply that change to all the selected controls.  You also do things like select multiple controls, then choose Arrange -> Left (Access 2007 ribbon).  Those options can make the fiddly adjustments less painful.  :-)

Comment: HansUp: Thank you! I didn't even know about the Arrange tab (called Format in 2010), they have an "Equal Horizontal" and "Equal Vertical" button that solve my problem perfectly.